# Scanner in method (do loop) not accepting greater/less than sign

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment where I need to make a Roulette program using a java program (Im using Eclipse). The program has a requirment that states: Given the following method *heading*, you must write the corresponding *definition* for a int return method that reads, validates, and returns a number to bet on, which must be between 0 and 36. (The heading is **public static int getNumber(Scanner stdIn)**). The problem I'm having is with the while statement, because it doesnt recognize the greater/less than symbol. How do I go about fixing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program08 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    welcome();
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    number = getNumber(stdIn);

    }
public static void welcome()
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to Roulette!");
    System.out.println("Number bets payout: 35:1");
}
public static int getNumber(Scanner stdIn)
{
    do
    {
        //int play;
        System.out.println("Enter the number to bet on [0-36]: ");
        //play = stdIn.nextInt;
    }
    while (stdIn<0 || stdIn>36);

}
}//end of program
```

Comment: Why do you compare Scanner object to numbers??  You need to read a number from the scanner and then compare it to your values.

Answer (score 1):

You have compilation errors in your program. Here is the code that compiles correctly,

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program08{

    public static void main(String[] args){
            welcome();
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        number = getNumber(stdIn);
    }

    public static void welcome(){
      System.out.println("Welcome to Roulette!");
      System.out.println("Number bets payout: 35:1");
    }

    public static int getNumber(Scanner stdIn){
        int play = 0;
        do{
          System.out.println("Enter the number to bet on [0-36]: ");
          play = stdIn.nextInt();
      } while (play < 0 || play > 36);
        return play;
    }
}
```

What were the fixes:

1. In `getNumber()` declare `play` (the integer variable where
   you are going to store the choice of the user) outside of the
   do-while loop. You do that so the while section of the do-while statement can access that variable.
2. Use the `Scanner` object (`stdIn`) to read a number from the user and
   store it in `play`. This does that: `play = stdIn.nextInt()` (assuming the user will enter a number and not some
   arbitrary text which would produce an error or more precisely *raise an exception*).
3. Compare the value of `play` in the while section of the do-while
   statement. What you wrote, `stdIn < 0` is fundamentally wrong since you're comparing a `Scanner` object, which is not a number, to a number. Imagine in place of a
   `Scanner` having another object, say a `Person`. Could you say that George (an instance of `Person`) is greater than zero? Obviously you cannot. You could
   say though that George's age (which is a number) is greater than zero, `George.age > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to call the method `nextInt()` on the scanner to get the actual value.

So outside your loop, declare an `int input`, set it at the end of the loop and then check that:

```
int input;

do {
    //... stuff

    input = stdIn.nextInt();
} while(input < 0 || input > 36);
```